# Starting an Image array at the second index item in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, indexpath

I am trying to get the "var product" array to start populating the cells after the first UICollectionViewcell "newCell". newCell will always appear the same way and will always be present. productCell may have different names and labels and may not always be present. The array of images "products" will continue to grow and I can currently see the second item, but the first image is blocked by the newCell collection view cell.

```
var products: [itemCellContent] = {



    var eggs = itemCellContent()
    eggs.itemName = "Eggs"
    eggs.itemImageName = "eggs"
    eggs.Quantity = "1"

    var Toast = itemCellContent()
    Toast.itemName = "Bread"
    Toast.itemImageName = "bread"
    Toast.Quantity = "5"


    return [eggs, Toast]
}()

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == 0
    {
        let newCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: addCellID, for: indexPath) as! addProductCell


        print("Rounds corners")

        return newCell
    } else {
        let productCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! productCellLayout
        productCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 252, green: 252, blue: 252) //off white blue color
        productCell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        print("Rounds corners")

        productCell.gItem = products[indexPath.item]

        //collectionview.insertIems(at: indexPaths)

        //Shadow
        productCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        productCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3.0)
        productCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        productCell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        productCell.layer.masksToBounds = false
        productCell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: productCell.bounds, cornerRadius: productCell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath;
        return productCell
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me get the "var product" array to recognize the second cell as the first cell that can be populated please let me know what I can do.

[This is what I see when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCKWq.png)
[This is what I want to see,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NeAT.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just use productCell.gItem = products[indexPath.row - 1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you need to do two things to achieve this.
First, return number of cells to be one more than number of items:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let _ = products {
        return products!.count + 1
    }
    return 1
}
```

Next, return appropriate cell instance based on above.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == 0
    {
        let newCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: addCellID, for: indexPath) as! addProductCell


        print("Rounds corners")

        return newCell
    } else {
        let productCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! productCellLayout
        productCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 252, green: 252, blue: 252) //off white blue color
        productCell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        print("Rounds corners")

        productCell.gItem = products[indexPath.item - 1] // Here's a difference than before

        //collectionview.insertIems(at: indexPaths)

        //Shadow
        productCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        productCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3.0)
        productCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        productCell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        productCell.layer.masksToBounds = false
        productCell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: productCell.bounds, cornerRadius: productCell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath;
        return productCell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `products` array has only two items. Just add a dummy cell at the begging of the array, so you can modify the collection at index zero without missing other items.

```
var products: [itemCellContent] = {

    var dummyCell = itemCellContent()

    var eggs = itemCellContent()
    eggs.itemName = "Eggs"
    eggs.itemImageName = "eggs"
    eggs.Quantity = "1"

    var Toast = itemCellContent()
    Toast.itemName = "Bread"
    Toast.itemImageName = "bread"
    Toast.Quantity = "5"


    return [dummyCell, eggs, Toast]
}()
```

Comment: I did have that but I wanted a way that I didn't force me to use a dummy cell.